# How to remove HTML attribute starting with letter + number?

Tags: jquery, regex, attr

I want to remove attribute tags that start with a letter "z" followed by any digits ("z#").

But I have errors as you can see when running this snippet:

```js
$("#main article").each(function(){
  var DE = new RegExp(/z{1}(\d{0,})\w+/); 

  $(this).removeAttr(function (){
    return (this.match(DE));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="main">
  <article z1  > AAA </article>
  <article z2  > BBB </article>
  <article z3  > CCC </article>
  <article z101> DDD </article>
  <article z102> EEE </article>
  <article z103> FFF </article>
</section>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Don't use `new RegExp` for constants, only when you're creating regular expressions dynamically.

Comment: The argument to `removeAttr()` isn't a function, it's a string that names the attribute. You need to loop over all the attributes, test whether it matches, and then remove it.

Comment: your regexp will match `z` with no number after it, since the quantifier starts with `0`. Use `\d+` to match at least 1 number.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, who/what inserted those HTML5 invalid attributes in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in your attempt:

- `removeAttr` doesn't take a function as argument. You have to pass the name of the attribute (a string).
- There is no iteration happening over the attributes. For that you could use the `this.attributes` collection
- The `\w+` would allow letters to follow at the end. That's not what you stated in the question.
- The regex lacks end-of-string markers, so it would also allow the pattern to occur somewhere in the middle of a long string with other characters.

Also:

- You don't need the `RegExp` constructor when you already have a regex literal
- `{1}` is useless in a regex.
- `{0,}` is equivalent to `*`
- To check whether a string matches with a regex, you don't need `match` (which returns an array), but can better use `test`.

```js
$("#main article").each(function(i, article) {
    $(this.attributes).each(function () {
        if (/^z\d*$/.test(this.name)) $(article).removeAttr(this.name);
    });
});
console.log($("#main").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="main">
  <article z1  > AAA </article>
  <article z2  > BBB </article>
  <article z3  > CCC </article>
  <article z101> DDD </article>
  <article z102> EEE </article>
  <article z103> FFF </article>
</section>
```